# Is there any table changes tracking tool for mysql which will log all changes into other table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a Project management system on PHP (CodeIgniter framework), Mysql, AJAX, XAMPP, JQUERY. I need a customizable table changes tracking tool which will log all changes into another table in same database for mysql. Basically I need to have a table which will have log details of updates, inserts and deletes on a database tables with what column has changed to what (summary). So that I can create a report from that table with changes to any particular table.

If there is no tool, I have already started working on my own solution where I am looking at two options.

**One** is having triggers on all tables which will create a row for each update and inserts with old data and new changed data. But here I need external user input as update comments from the user. How can I insert that data from a trigger. This is some what complex. Please suggest me any solution.

**Second** one is I will track the changes from PHP and insert every time when I do update and Insert which is more work but easier to implement.

Which one do you prefer? If not suggest me a tool which will take care of all this and insert into a new table in the same database. Or am I missing any thing simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely prefer doing this in application code rather than in the DB. An ORM is wonderful at handling this kind of thing as it gives an easy way of tracking and intercepting changes.

If you have a sensible abstraction over your database access then it should be pretty simple to intercept any database calls in your PHP code and do the logging there. Of course if you are building up SQL manually and then calling the database directly there is no central place for you to log changes.

Comment: I am building up SQL queries by utility functions in codeigniter which will take data and give sql query string.

Comment: Hai @Enjoycoding may you share your sample code, please.

Answer (score 2):

Use stored procedures for all your updating/inserting/deleting
The procedure should take all the arguments it needs to perform the given task plus one argument that will contain the comment. Then just update/insert/delete and make a record (with the comment) in the log table.

ps: can't see how you would be able to use some tool if you need to insert comments (same problem than triggers).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. But I am not so good at stored procedures. Also I am not getting an idea of how to get only the changed columns old and new data.Can you suggest any example of such stored procedure for mysql. Thanks again

Comment: Well you would have to pull the old data from the table and compare each field with the new values. This can be done either in PHP or in the stored procedure.
If you don't know stored procedures then I'm afraid your only options is to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net) supports database replication and tracking changes since the latest version

Comment: phpmyadmin supports that. God I did not know that. How can I use that to insert all logs into new table as per my requirement?? Please let me know as soon as possible. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: http://blog.cihar.com/archives/2009/08/27/summer_of_code_in_phpmyadmin/ gives some insight

Comment: I think PhpMyAdmin logs only the requests done through itself. In that case I need other solution.